# How to find the highest number less than target value in a list?

Tags: python, binary-search

I am trying to write a binary search that takes a sorted list and finds the largest number less than a target value:

```py
def binary_max(list, target)
    hi=len(list)-1
    lo=0
    while lo<=hi:
        mid=(hi+lo)//2
        midval=list[mid]
        if midval > target:
            hi=mid-1
        elif midval <= target:
            lo=mid
        if hi==lo:
            break
    return(list[mid])
pass
```

However, when for example there is a list with length 2, `hi=1` and the `mid` value will always be stuck on `lo`.

Is there anyway to avoid this problem?

Comment: It might sound silly but: Can you update your question to include the full function and the code to call it?

Comment: seldon the `while` loop is idiomatic in Python unless it is an infinite loop (`while True`)

Comment: @PauloScardine, Yet if you look in `bisect.py`...

Comment: @gnibbler: this module looks like C translated to Python, but I can't think of a better algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The `bisect` module provides functions to do exactly that. Use [bisect.bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect).

Comment: can you show how bisect would work when target is not in list?

Comment: @alancalvitti docs are pretty clear on that. `The returned insertion point i partitions the array a into two halves so that all(val <= x for val in a[lo : i]) for the left side and all(val > x for val in a[i : hi]) for the right side`

Answer (score 0):

When you `break` out of the loop, `mid` still contains the value from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest number less than the target value as follows:

```
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
arr = list(arr)
indices = [v for i,v in enumerate(arr) if v != max(arr)]
print(max(indices))
```

Here I'm demonstrating it for target value = max value in the list. You can change max value to any target value you want.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple function to do that. Hope it works:

```
def bin_search(list, target):
    if target not in list:
        return None
    list.sort()
    return list[list.index(target)-1]
```

Comment: you could simplify it like this `list[list.index(target)-1]`

Comment: He does, I was just saying how you could simplify the last two lines of your answer.

Comment: Doesn't work if target value is not in list - there's no assumption of that by OP.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function that does the trick, starts at the highest number and returns as soon as the evaluated number is lower than the target :D

```
def largest_less_than_target(my_list, target):
    for a in sorted(my_list, reverse=True):
        if a < target: return a
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32201604)